# GROUP BY clause ignoring rows and data

Tags: php, mysql

As we know `GROUP BY` clause return data by ignoring duplicate data by specifying particular `GROUP BY 'user_id'` , but i want to do that `GROUP BY` ignore table row but i want to combine data of that row in array , means i want all data but in filtered row
i want to something like

```
id | name | user_id
-------------------
1    abc     20
2    trt     19
3    sdf     20
4    khg     22
5    fdf     20
6    lnm     22



id | name | user_id
-------------------
1    abc,sdf,fdf     20
2    trt             19
3    khg,lnm         22
```

Comment: Where is your query, table structure and effort??

Comment: Provide sample data along with expected result in to the question.

Comment: i am using cakephp

$driverlocation_data = $this->DriverLocation->find('all',array(
           'conditions'=>array('DriverLocation.dispensary_id'=>$dispensary_id),
           'group'=>array('DriverLocation.driver_id')
           ));

Comment: i updated my question. please check

Comment: Have a look at [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this. Try this query -

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) name, user_id FROM students GROUP BY user_id
```

> The **GROUP_CONCAT** function concatenates strings from a group into one string with various options.

**Update**

To implement it in CakePhp -

```
$driverlocation_data = $this->DriverLocation->find(
    'all',
     array(
     'conditions'=>array('DriverLocation.dispensary_id'=>$dispensary_id),
     'fields' => array('id', 'GROUP_CONCAT(name) name', 'user_id')                                      
     'group'=>array('DriverLocation.driver_id') 
    )
);
```

Comment: could you tell me how to fetch GROUP_CONCAT in cakephp?

current query

$driverlocation_data = $this->DriverLocation->find('all',array( 'conditions'=>array('DriverLocation.dispensary_id'=>$dispensary_id), 'group'=>array('DriverLocation.driver_id') ));

Comment: Just define the field array in options and set the field.

Comment: i didn't get you, could you please write some code for me.??

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query.

```
Select id, GROUP_CONCAT(name), user_id FROM table_name GROUP BY user_id
```

I have Used group_concat for name column.